# error while pushing to Heroku after committing runtime.txt change: Requested runtime 'python-3.9.5' is not available for this stack (heroku-22)

Tags: python, heroku

On my first attempt at pushing to Heroku (`$ git subtree push --prefix <my-subfolder> heroku main`) my `runtime.txt` file had `python-3.9.5` in it. From that push I received the following output

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote:  !     Requested runtime 'python-3.9.5' is not available for this stack (heroku-22).
remote:  !     For supported versions, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

After checking the link in the output, I changed the `runtime.txt` file to have the recommended `python-3.10.7` version and committed the change. When pushing the commit I received the exact same message `remote:  !     Requested runtime 'python-3.9.5' is not available for this stack (heroku-22).`

I'm not sure where it's reading the old version from since I changed it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't solved the issue but just found a workaround by downgrading the stack from 22 -> 20 on the current app `$ heroku stack:set heroku-20`